# How to parse a list of dates and set them to a AlarmManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am retreiving a list of dates from HTML.

The list is set to a List when it is retreived.

I want to use a SimpleDate Parser(which i know how to do) to parse and set the date for the AlarmManager.

Since it is more than one Date. How could i create a method for this? To create a Alarm for each Date.

The first time the list of dates is loaded i would like it to parse the dates and set an alarm for each.

And if its more than one alarm on one day, how could i combine them as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the alarm as you contain the size of the List object which contains the date.

now parse it and set in alarm with the pending object in any loop like for loop.

just use the same object for the Intent, PendingIntent AlarmManager

in the for loop do like this way

```
Calendar setAlarm=Calendar.getInstance();
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

for(int i=0;i<listDate.size();i++){
    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),"YOUR BROADCAST CLASS");
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

   /// if you parse date direct then here pass
   setAlarm.setTime(sdf.parse(listDate.get(0));
   am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setAlarm.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
}
```

Comment: Will this overwrite the alarms? And i am using an ArrayList btw. if they will give you a better idea of what i am doing.

Comment: no because in the getBroadcast the second parameter is request code so if you pass the same intent with the different request code then you can set the different alarm with same instant

Comment: see i have pass the "i" so "i" will be increase every time and requestcode will be changed

Answer (score 1):

Set an alarm for each, it is possible and supported.
However, please note that you have to differentiate the alarms in such a way so that Android won't "overwrite" the old ones.
The thing is that if 2 alarms use the same intent params and extras the new one will overwrite the old one.

For example, you should change the requestId param like this:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(**uniqueRequestId**));
        sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, **uniqueRequestId**, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, sender);
```